# how to select and copy range of data through vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting stuck on  a simple line of code. For this section of my procedure I simply want to merge data from one tab to another. Below is the code i have to copy the information from "Page1-2" and paste in at the next blank row of "Page1-1":

```
Sheets("Page1-2").Activate
ActiveSheet.Range("A5:AJ66000").Copy
Sheets("Page1-1").Activate
Columns("A").Find("", Cells(Rows.Count, "A")).Select
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial
```

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the problem with this code? Do you get an error? Do the individual lines of code work? Did you test them with a MsgBox or the console?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a variable to hold the last row in your `Page1-1` sheet.

```
Sub test()
Dim k   As Integer

Sheets("Page1-2").Range("A5:AJ66000").Copy
With Sheets("Page1-1")
    k = .Cells(1048576, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    If k > 1 Then k = k + 1  ' this is so we don't overwrite the last row on previously copied data
    .Cells(k, 1).PasteSpecial
End With
End Sub
    End Sub
```

Note: It's a good idea to learn how to [avoid using `.Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros), you can see in my code above how to combine those two lines into one.